# Trying to connect to docker container through localhost

Tags: docker, nginx, linux-mint

I have an image setup that runs nginx and php-fpm for laravel, I know that the image is working because I used it before both on a live server and on my local Ubuntu. My problem is that I changed over to linux mint and used the same command

that being 
`docker run --name social-server -itd -v ~/Desktop/nginx/conf/:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled -v ~/Desktop/nginx/logs/:/var/log/nginx --link social-db:mysql -v ~/Desktop/dashboard:/app -v ~/Desktop/secv/:/ssl -p 80:80 -p 443:443 php-base`

and for some reason I cant get it to connect from `localhost` in browser.

Checked the logs for nginx and they aren't being written to(not `error` or `access`) so it is not connecting to the container in general

**EDIT:** Error gotten in browser

```
This site can’t be reached

The connection was reset.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
ReloadHIDE DETAILS
```

Thanks in advance for help

**EDIT**

I've broken down the run command and found out that it only stops working when I add `-v ~/Desktop/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

Comment: Can you specify the error message ?

Comment: @papey edited the post to include the error from browser

Comment: Is the container up and running? What do you get with `docker ps -a`?

Comment: @tgogos yup the container is running fine, no errors either

Comment: Find your container's IP address with `docker inspect <container ID>`, and try to connect with `http://your-container-ip` instead of `http://localhost`.

Comment: @tgogos This site can’t be reached

172.17.0.3 refused to connect.

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the edit I broke down the run command and found that it was 
`-v ~/Desktop/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` why this is I don't know but I took it out and everything is working fine... I will simply use /etc/nginx/sites-available/default in the container and edit it to work how I would like. Thank you for all the help